# How to best handle environment based configs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I'd like to know how bad the approach below is to capturing custom config parameters across multiple environments. This is meant to address cases where there are very large configuration parameters that may need to be organized several layers deep.

**Requires the following features:**
- setting the config param needs to be very simple, easy to copy/paste
- accessing the config param needs to be terse
- should be programatic for flexibility, no yaml (unless convinced)
- configs per environment need not be mandatory, should fall back on a sane default (in this case, the :base config)
- initializing config object needs to be terse
- environment details need to be hidden

**Shortcomings of this implementation:**
- eval is evil? Is eval really that bad in this case? Users do not control the values, they are all hardcoded in the source.
- not the fastest, but in my case it doesn't matter
- initializing the Hash is weird
- the "get" calls are kind of weird too

This was created because I needed to have a robust way of processing a file that could have a large amount of parameters.  These params can vary across environments, so being able to easily override the base values (per environment) is critical.

These params also need to be tightly coupled with the models that they are called in, so initializers and globals are not an option.

If anyone has a much better way of accomplishing these goals in a much more elegant way, I'd love to hear.  This code is not good idomatic design, so I'm hoping to get some other ideas, like a strong oop approach.

```
class Paramz
  def initialize(params)
    @env = :development # Rails.env.to_sym
    @params = params
  end

  def get(values)
    eval_hash(values.split("."))
  end

  protected

  def eval_hash(values)
    new_val = String.new

    values.map { |v| new_val = new_val + "[:#{v}]" }
    base, env = eval("@params[:base]" + new_val), eval("@params[@env]" + new_val)

    return env != {} ? env : base
  end
end

p = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }

# file config
p[:base][:file][:path] = "/opt/files"
p[:qa][:file][:path] = "c:\\files\\"
p[:production][:file][:path] = "/opt/projects/final"

params = Paramz.new(p)

# env = :base
puts params.get("file.path")
# >> "/opt/files" # returns :base config

# env = :development
# puts params.get("file.path")
# >> "/opt/files" # no :development config, falls back on :base

# env = :production
# puts params.get("file.path")
# >> "/opt/projects/final" # return :production config
```

Comment: I really like using environment variables for configurations that changes based on your environment, or for sensitive values. check out https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a close look at dotenv.  Not sure if it will handle all of my requirements, but I'll definitely find out.